# Are PHP Sessions values possible to be changed from page1 to page2?

Tags: php, session

I am new to Sessions and I am concern about the security.

My question is if the use of Sessions is secure enough, so that a user will not be able to change the values from page1 to page2 with the use of a plugin or any advanced methods.

My purpose is to clear up my mind on what to choose between

1. to pass all the needed variables through sessions or
2. to pass only the id through post/get and get the needed data from
   the database.

What I do is to in page1.php to submit `$name` and on page2.php `$_POST['name']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session data is stored on the server. The only session-related data that should EVER be sent to the user is the session ID token - this is generally a randomly generated string, and is basically meaningless by itself.

Unless your code provides a method for a user to directly change a value in the session, it is impossible for a user to change the session data unless they hack the server.

Comment: So you suggest me to make use of sessions instead of the classic `in page1.php submit $name and on page2.php $_POST['name']` ?

Comment: depends on your needs. either works fine, but both have upsides/downsides.

Answer (score 0):

No, with "plugins" it's not possible to change it. If you're setting session variables from GET or POST variables, it's changable and cheatable from user's input. Be aware of that

Comment: @Nikolai: if you want to pass post to another page, it'S fine to use session